# How to use kafka-node under typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka

I need to use kafka-node under typescript:

```
const kafkaHost = 'localhost:9092';
const client = new Client({ kafkaHost });
```

After launching index.ts I get this error:

```
 Property '_write' in type 'ProducerStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Writable'.
  Type '(message: ProduceRequest, encoding: "utf8" | "buffer", cb: (error: any, data: any) => any) => void' is not assignable to type '(chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: (error?: Error | null | undefined) => void) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'encoding' and 'encoding' are incompatible.
      Type 'BufferEncoding' is not assignable to type '"utf8" | "buffer"'.
        Type '"ascii"' is not assignable to type '"utf8" | "buffer"'.

143   _write (message: ProduceRequest, encoding: 'buffer' | 'utf8', cb: (error: any, data: any) => any): void;
```

I think problem is in types, so I dont have installed `@types/kafka-node`, nevertheless it is deprecated.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kafka-node now comes with it's own pre-defined types for Typescript. You can refer them from [here](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/blob/master/types/index.d.ts)

Regarding your problem, you need the import proper types before using it:

```
import { KafkaClient as Client } from 'kafka-node';

const kafkaHost = 'localhost:9092';
const client = new Client({ kafkaHost });
```

Comment: I've tried importing all the types. But I am getting the same error, while importing kafka-node itself. Can you elaborate your solution ?

Comment: I still get TypeError: kafka_node_1.KafkaClient is not a constructor when trying to instantiate KafkaClient (Or Client in this case) and both gives me the same "not a constructor" typeerror.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reported bug in kafka-node with no official solution yet. The best answer for this so far is... don't let typescript check kafka-node source code.

Add `"skipLibCheck": true` to tsconfig.json

see here:
https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/1412